# Android extras bundle returning zero instead of actual long value?

Tags: android, long-integer, extras

This was working before, but now the .getLong method is returning a zero.

```
    public class TaskerDBadapter 
{       
    public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
}


Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) 
    {
        rowId = extras.getLong(TaskerDBadapter.KEY_ROWID);
    }
```

When clearly that key has the value 14.  If I inspect extras, I see the following:

Bundle[{_id=14, StartDate=3/17/2011, Pattern=Once, Description=Test}]

What gives?

Comment: can you pull the other items out?

Comment: Yes...  they are all successfully pulled out and used to populate UI elements.

Comment: where are you doing the `intent.putExtra(TaskerDBadapter.KEY_ROWID, rowId);` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere the code changed after testing this piece of it previously, and I startedputting it in the bundle as an int, apparently.  Found after using extras.getInt(x) evaluated with the proper value.